# Error after installing TFS 2012 - Update 2

Tags: tfs

I have one TFS 2012 environment with Update 1 and today I updated this environment to Update 2, the installation is completed with sucess, but my portal web access is not working and is returning the bellow error

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Before the update, my environment was running smoothly but now after the installationd Updete 2 is not working

This error is about ASP NET MVC, all right?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I did not installed update 2 yet myself but did you check your `administration console`? And check also your `event viewer`, maybe you'll find interesting information/errors there that can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed update 2 but haven't encountered the issue you have. I did have some issues and ended up turning off the application pools for the Portal and disabling TFS on the server by using the `TFSServiceControl quiesce` command before installing the update.

One thing I have noticed is that TFS Update 2 installs a .Net 4.0 version of 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment' into the GAC an the location:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35

Assuming you are running x64 there is a .Net 2.0 version of this assembly in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies

Alternatively for x32 it should be in

C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies

I would suggest copying the .Net 2.0 version of this DLL from this location to the TFS Portal's bin folder and seeing if this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classic hunt and peck from the old days. I have no idea what types of installations this affects, but mine was a 2008 x64. Basically, I went to the web.config of the team (program files, long path, 11.0, web...\bin) and enabled error reporting.

Then I loaded it with IE in localhost addressing to get to the team project. Basically, it's looking for a bunch of .NET 2.0 DLLs. Copy each one it is looking for (find them doing a dir  /s off the root, there are a few) to the local bin folder.

Thought these days had passed. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem after upgrading TFS2012 RTM to update 4.

I was able to resolve the problem by amending the user of the Application Pool to a TFS Administrator user (it was set as Network Service I think).